# Bathroom hot water issue

Tags: plumbing

We just did a small bathroom remodel.  The sink and the bathtub are connected to the same hot water line. Now I am not getting any hot water in the bathtub but the sink has hot water. The plumber did some adjustments under the sink and it worked worked . Today when I tried to turn the hot water in the tub Iam getting only cold water. The house is less then one year old and all the faucet are in good condition. Can anyone have any idea what the issue is. Thanks

Comment: What type of tub valve to you have?  On single-handle models, there can be internal settings for how hot the water gets, and if not set correctly, it may take a very long time (if ever) to get hot.

Comment: I have a double valve. But I was getting hot water before the remodel project started and also after while the plumber did the testing yesterday

Comment: So, when you test it are you turning on only the hot valve in the tub? I just can't imagine what could cause a pipe to give hot water one day, but not the next, regardless of anything that could have been done under the adjacent sink.  Is there a hot-water recirculating pump in the house (not common)?

Comment: I am turned the hot water tap only first then I also tried the cold just to make sure. Either way no success. There is no hot water recirculating pump in the house. How come the sink faucet is working normal. The plumber adjusted something under the sink like where the hot and cold pipe connects. Then we got the hot water yesterday. But today only cold water. I don't know which one to adjust or turn.

Comment: I am turning both hot and the cold to test it. The plumber adjusted something under the sink yesterday then we got the hot water.  But today no hot water. No hot water recirculating pump in the house.  Also the sink and rub are close to each other.

Comment: Turn off the power or gas to the water heater, then shut of the water supply to the water heater.  Then try to turn on the hot water in the sink or in the tub.  If you get a steady stream of water, then the hot and cold water pipes are connected somewhere, and you have a serious problem.  The hot and cold pipes should be completely separate, and you should either get hot water all the time, or not get any water at all.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of that the plumber adjusted under the sink is he swapper the hot and cold lines which had been installed backwards. If the hot water tank is at a distant location it would take sometime before hot water reached the faucet. The same would be true if you have a tankless water heater; standing water in the hot line cools when the faucet is closed for awhile.

Comment: He initialed installed the sink hot and cold water connection flipped then he swapped them again . When we did the test it was fine. Then today suddenly the hot water is not Working in the tub but works in the sink where both are placed next to each other.

Comment: The connection of the sink should have no effect on anything else in the house.  The fact that the plumber thought that changing anything on the sink is very questionable to me.  The sink faucet could be completely removed and the tub should still work fine.

Comment: The plumber said the hot water line for the tub is connected from under the sink where the water line is located.

Comment: The only other thought is the plumber has made an error during the remodel. He probably connected the hot to the cold and visa versa. It would be best to call him back to re-check his work.